# SQL identifying the first occurance in a list

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server I'm trying to label the first occurrence in a query result, so for results like this...

[image]

I can identify the first of each like this:

[image]

Can this be done is a case statement or similar?  Help much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: "first" ordered by what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use of row_number() should enable this

```
select
   breakfast
 , case when rn = 1 then 1 else 0 end as first_occur
from (
       select 
         breakfast
       , row_number() over (partition by breakfast order by ID DESC) as rn
       from your_table
     ) as x
```

but it isn't known what the order by is (I've assumed ID DESC), there might be a datetime or something else in the table to use for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a CTE (SQL 2005 and later) with an over clause and a ranking function.

I presume you will have some other critera as to which `Breakfast` you want to see first, use the `ORDER BY` to specify that.

`RowNumber` with then tell you how many times it has occurred.

An example below for you to adapt

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
    Breakfast VARCHAR(10) 
); 

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('Eggs')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('Fish')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('Fish')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('Eggs')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('Bacon')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('Bacon')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('Eggs')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('Fish')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('Bacon')

;WITH t AS (
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Breakfast ORDER BY Breakfast) AS RowNumber
   FROM @tbl 
)
SELECT Breakfast, (CASE WHEN RowNumber = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As FirstOccurance
FROM t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using SQL Server Windowing Functions :

[SQL Server MSDN documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)